# Python Keyboard library how to wait until a keyboard is released

Tags: python, keyboard, timing, keylogger

I'm looking for a way to wait till a key is released. The way I do this would preferably use keyboard library since it is already introduced in my script. The reason I want to do this is because I'm reading keystrokes from the keyboard but it's repeating the keystrokes at least 20 times a second. I want to be able to just capture the keystroke once on its own, so I don't know how to do it. The only way I can think of is to wait until the key is released until more inputs are accepted.

Any help is appreciated.

```
import pyautogui, time, keyboard
from datetime import datetime

output = str("")

now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
print(dt_string)    

characters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", " ", "backspace"]

outputFile = open("keylog_out.txt", "a+")

outputFile.write("\n=================================\n" + dt_string + "\n=================================\n\n")

while True:
    for i in characters:
        if keyboard.is_pressed(i):
            output = (output + i)
            print(output)
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("escape") and keyboard.is_pressed("shift"):
            print("Escape Modifier Pressed")
            outputFile.write(output + "\n\n=================================\n\n")
            outputFile.close()
            exit()
```

Comment: How would I implement that though? I'll attach my code to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the right module?
https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#api
check this too
https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#common-patterns-and-mistakes

---

https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.on_release_key

```
keyboard.on_release_key(key, callback, suppress=False)
```

I've never used this, but it looks like this is to register your hook with a callback

---

https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardwaithotkeynone-suppressfalse-trigger_on_releasefalse

```
keyboard.wait(hotkey=None, suppress=False, trigger_on_release=False)
```

or you can wait on events using blocking

Comment: Do you have any examples of how to implement this in my code? I'm not sure how I'd integrate this

Comment: If you want to just have one print happen; register an event. If you want to loop and monitor the keys, you could store down keys in a list, The API page has alot of recipes

Comment: Would this not need me to repeat this code for every character though? I'm looking for efficient code so I'm not sure how I would be able to do this.

Comment: Please could you show this in an example? My two braincells are rubbing together as hard as they can with no result. I understand you've shown the code above but I don't know how to adapt this to the context of my code.

Comment: I am really struggling to use this mini-markdown but, [Repeatedly waiting for a key press](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#repeatedly-waiting-for-a-key-press) `# Do this instead
while True:
    keyboard.wait('space')
    print('space was pressed! Waiting on it again...')``# or this
keyboard.add_hotkey('space', lambda: print('space was pressed!'))
keyboard.wait()`